# Delete permission of your own app from your profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am testing my app, and when I had authorized my app with my user profile, I only gave it access to certain set of pages. Now I want to test different pages, but there seems to be no way to re-authorize the app.

When I request authorization again, Facebook just returns the existing authorization.

In my user profile on Facebook, Settings, App and Websites,
I can see third party apps and remove them, but, I do not see any apps that I am an admin of here. How to remove your own apps permission from your profile or page?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of a GUI way to do it. There is a way to do it via `Graph API`.  I'm using the [dev documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking/).

To revoke a specific permission
you have to make call to the `Graph API` endpoint:

```
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}
```

To completetly de-authorize an app or revoke login.  You have to make call to the `Graph API` endpoint:

```
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions
```

### Here is excerpt from the documentation :

> ### Revoking Permissions
>
> Apps can let people revoke permissions that were previously granted.
>   For example, your app could have a settings page that lets someone
>   disable publishing to Facebook. That settings page could also revoke
>   the publish_actions permission at the same time.
>
> You can revoke a specific permission by making a call to a Graph API
>   endpoint:
>
> DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}
>
> This request must be made with a user access token or an app access
>   token for the current app. If the request is successful, you will
>   receive a response of true.
>
> ### Revoking Login
>
> You can also let people completely de-authorize an app, or revoke
>   login, by making a call to this Graph API endpoint:
>
> DELETE /{user-id}/permissions
>
> This request must be made with a valid user access token or an app
>   access token for the current app. If the request is successful, your
>   app receives a response of true. If the call is successful, any user
>   access token for the person will be invalidated and they will have to
>   log in again. Because you're de-authorizing your app, they will also
>   have to grant access to your app as if they were logging in for the
>   first time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out 'Expired' tab in the 'Settings > App and Websites'? Actually it should contain the rest of your apps, if some of them not presents in main ('Active') tab.

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=inactive

As it says:

> Data Access: Expired These are apps and websites you've logged into
>   with Facebook and may not have used in a while. They may still have
>   access to info you previously shared, but their ability to make
>   additional requests for private info has expired. Learn More You can
>   still log into these apps and websites using Facebook.